# working with virtualenv without Python in Windows path

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have to do some work with a company with security restrictions on their computers.

I need to set Python2.7 virtualenv on their Windows10 machine but can't add python to Windows path. I installed Python through the Windows Software Centre. The interpreter is in usual C:\Python27\python.exe but it is not added to Windows path. When I run python in CMD it is not recognizable although C:\Python27\python opens the interpreter.

The problem is that to add it to Windows path I need admin privileges. It is simply not possible. I know the obvious answer is to contact admin but again it is not an option.

So the problem is, having this setup I need to install virtualenv, inside create all my environment and work on it. 
I can't find the way to do it without Python in the path.

Comment: How would you do it with python in tha path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually install several system-wide pythons versions on my windows boxes with the only purpose of creating virtualenvs and that's more than ok. In fact, i strongly recommend to avoid polluting PATH with system-wide python paths at all. Using just virtualenvs is really a good way to go.

That said, if you're creating virtualenvs manually (ie: not using any IDE/plugin to manage this process for you) you can just do it on the command prompt like this:

```
> cd c:\python27\Scripts
> pip install virtualenv
```

and then just using `c:\python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe` to create your new virtualenvs, for instance, something like this would do it:

```
> c:\python27\Scripts\virtualenv --python=c:\python27\python.exe foo_venv
```

That said, if it's more convenient for you to have virtualenv executable reachable from the console (ie: `where virtualenv` finds its path) you can just add it temporarily to your console session with something like:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Or even better, just create a shortcut of one bat file which spawns your favourite console (cmd prompt, conemu, ...) setting PATH on that particular session, that way you don't need to persist the variable PATH with admin privileges.

Comment: Thanks, for support. I managed to install virtualenv.
Saying so, for some reason pip did not work as expected. It gave Errno10061. Maybe it is still firewalled somehow. 
I downloaded virtualenv .whl and installed from local file

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a Virtual environment containing python 3(which I created from my home computer).  My work computer has exactly the same fate as OP. So when I copy my venv into my pendrive and paste it in my work computer,  the venv is activated but all the modules that I installed in the venv are not available. I cannot even access the copy of python in venv.

Comment: Since my question can be easily marked as duplicate,  so I felt asking in comment would be a better option

Answer (score 1):

You could run: `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python27\` from a command prompt and it will add the python to path temporary  (i.e will be gone when the command prompt is closed)