# How to run "python setup.py install" when python is not recognized by windows?

Tags: python

The command: "python setup.py install" is not recognized by Windows Command Prompt. Because Python is installed inside a virtual environment, so there is no path to any Python folder in the system environment variables.

How to do you install the setup.py file in this situation?

Comment: What keeps you from installing Python to run Python code?

Comment: I have installed Python inside a virtual environment, and it is inside this environment I want to install that setup.py. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46363175/working-with-virtualenv-without-python-in-windows-path help?

Comment: Did you _activate_ the virtual environment? How did you _create_ the virtual environment without having Python installed?

Comment: If I remember the sequence correctly, I think I downloaded Anaconda first, then created the virtual environment, then installed Python inside that environment. I have no Python folder, I have looked everywhere on my drive. Yet inside the environment I use Python everyday.

Comment: Answer to Nico Haase. No, that didnt help. II is a different situation.